# python: DELETE points out of a very big 2D array and elements are float, like discarding unwanted points in KNN

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 2D array and I want to delete a point out of it but suppose it's so big meaning I can't specify an index and just grab it and the values of the array are float
How can I delete this point? With a LOOP and WITHOUT LOOP?? the following is 2D array and I want to delete [ 32.9,   23.]

```
[[ 1. ,  -1.4],
    [ -2.9,  -1.5],
    [ -3.6,  -2. ],
    [  1.5,   1. ],
    [  24. ,   11. ],
    [ -1. ,  1.4],
    [ 2.9,  1.5],
    [ 3.6,  2. ],
    [  -1.5,   -1. ],
    [  -24. ,   -11. ],
    [  32.9,   23. ],
    [-440. ,  310. ]]
```

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
this_point = np.asarray([ 32.9,   23.])

[x for x in y if x == point]

del datapoints[this_point]

np.delete(datapoints,len(datapoints), axis=0)

for this_point in datapoints:
        del this_point
```

when I do this, the this_point stays in after printing all points, what should I do?

Comment: `del this_point` deletes `this_point`. Have you read the docs for https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python can remove a list element by content, but numpy does only by index.  So, use "where" to find the coordinates of the matching row:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ 1. ,  -1.4],
    [ -2.9,  -1.5],
    [ -3.6,  -2. ],
    [  1.5,   1. ],
    [  24. ,   11. ],
    [ -1. ,  1.4],
    [ 2.9,  1.5],
    [ 3.6,  2. ],
    [  -1.5,   -1. ],
    [  -24. ,   -11. ],
    [  32.9,   23. ],
    [-440. ,  310. ]])

find = np.array([32.9,23.])

row = np.where( (a == find).all(axis=1))
print( row )

print(np.delete( a, row, axis=0 ) )
```

Output:

```
(array([10], dtype=int64),)
[[   1.    -1.4]
 [  -2.9   -1.5]
 [  -3.6   -2. ]
 [   1.5    1. ]
 [  24.    11. ]
 [  -1.     1.4]
 [   2.9    1.5]
 [   3.6    2. ]
 [  -1.5   -1. ]
 [ -24.   -11. ]
 [-440.   310. ]]

C:\tmp>
```

Comment: thanks,what to do if I want to delete its corresponding distance too?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  You haven't mentioned anything about distances here.

Comment: I know, but if I have their euclidean distance to this_point same 2D array and after deleting this_point, I'd want to delete the corresponding distance too.. is there a way to it? i tried same  solution as above, but didn't work, how can  I do it ?

Comment: `row` contains the row number to be deleted.  If the two arrays are in parallel, then you can use `np.delete` exactly like I did with `a`.